# Unnest nested tidydrc models

Tags: r, tidyverse, unnest, drc

**Problem**

I've been using a `tidy` wrapper for the `drc` package—`tidydrc`— to build growth curves which produces a `tidy` version of the normal output (best for `ggplot`). However, due to the inherit nesting of the models, I can't run simple `drc` functions since the models are nested inside a dataframe. I've attached code that mirrors `drc` and `tidydrc` package below.

---

**Goal**

To compare information criteria from multiple model fits for the `tidydrc` output using the `drc` function `mselect()`—ultimately to efficiently select the best fitting model.

---

**Ideal Result (works with `drc`)**

```
library(tidydrc) # To load the Puromycin data
library(drc)

model_1 <- drm(rate ~ conc, state, data = Puromycin, fct = MM.3())

mselect(model_1, list(LL.3(), LL.5(), W1.3(), W1.4(), W2.4(), baro5()))


# DESIRED OUTPUT SIMILAR TO THIS
         logLik       IC Lack of fit  Res var
MM.3  -78.10685 170.2137   0.9779485 70.54874 # Best fitting model
LL.3  -78.52648 171.0530   0.9491058 73.17059
W1.3  -79.22592 172.4518   0.8763679 77.75903
W2.4  -77.87330 173.7466   0.9315559 78.34783
W1.4  -78.16193 174.3239   0.8862192 80.33907
LL.5  -77.53835 177.0767   0.7936113 87.80627
baro5 -78.00206 178.0041   0.6357592 91.41919
```

---

**Not Working Example with `tidydrc`**

```
library(tidyverse) # tidydrc utilizes tidyverse functions

model_2 <- tidydrc_model(data = Puromycin, conc, rate, state, model = MM.3())
summary(model_2)
```

> Error: `summary.vctrs_list_of()` not implemented.

Now, I can manually tease apart the list of models in the dataframe `model_2` but can't seem to figure out the correct `apply` statements (it's a mess) to get this working.

---

**Progress Thus Far**

These both produce the same error, so at least I've subsetted a level down but now I'm stuck and pretty sure this is not the ideal solution.

```
mselect(model_2$drmod, list(LL.3(), LL.5(), W1.3(), W1.4(), W2.4(), baro5()))

model_2_sub <- model_2$drmod # Manually subset the drmod column

apply(model_2_sub, 2, mselect(list(LL.3(), LL.5(), W1.3(), W1.4(), W2.4(), baro5())))
```

> Error in UseMethod("logLik") : 
>     no applicable method for 'logLik' applied to an object of class "list"

I've even tried the `tidyverse` function `unnest()` to no avail

```
model_2_unnest <- model_2 %>% unnest_longer(drmod, indices_include = FALSE)
```

Comment: Can you please provide the desired output?

Comment: The desired output would be the similar to the result from first section of code that I posted: "**Ideal Result (works with `drc`)**" or something very similar. This might be unachievable because `tidydrc` makes lists of the models. I just need to unnest those lists and then run the `drc` function `mselect()` to compare model information criteria such as "logLik, IC, Lack of fit, and Res var".